# SharePoint Approval Workflow -- Multiple Approvers, only need 1 to Approve?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I have a custom workflow with multiple users that can approve of a announcement. Currently, both must approve to remove the status of "in progress". Is there a workaround for this? There is no "OR" operator available in SharePoint and it's driving me up the wall.Here is the workflow at the moment:

```
If Current Item:Body not equals Current Item:PriorBody
Start Approval process on Current Item with User1; User2

Else if Current Item:PriorWorkflow equals Approved
Set workflow status to Approved

If Current Item:PriorWorkflow equals Rejected
Set workflow status to Rejected
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a flexi task? you can set it to first response applies from the selected users.

Comment: I'll have to take a look at that - is that a setting or a feature which I can enable?

Comment: It should be one of the actions in the workflow itself

Comment: Ah okay - I found this tutorial: http://nintexdownload.com/Nsupport/tutorials/How%20to%20use%20the%20Assign%20Flexi%20Task%20action%20and%20show%20behavior%20outcome.pdf I am really confused though, do I have to make a new workflow and list to do this? I thought it would be something as simple as modifying the task itself.

Comment: Is Flex-Task something that is only available from a Nintex workflow?

Comment: Urm I am not too sure really, id imagine it would be available on all workflow solutions as its quite a useful action. As for creating a new list and workflow to use it, you shouldn't have to, you can just drop the action into the workflow and then configure it how you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a SharePoint group. Add both users to that group and then reference the group in the workflow. If this is a custom workflow that should be an easy fix.